# Why is setting an int to 0 considered moot after a null check?

Tags: c#, null, zero, dead-code

I've got this code setting an int val to 0 if it is null:

```
if (null == frbdcbl.QtyOrdered)
{
    frbdcbl.QtyOrdered = 0;
}
```

...but the assignment is greyed out, as if such an operation is moot. Why would that be? After all, null != 0.

The value being checked does not have a default value of 0 or such:

```
public class FillRateByDCByLocation
{
    . . .
    public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }
}
```

The code with the grayed out assignment (AddFillRateByDCByLocationRow(()) is called like so:

```
foreach (FillRateByDCByLocation frbdcbl in _fillRateByDCByLocGroupedSortedSummed)
{
    AddFillRateByDCByLocationRow(frbdcbl);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it a nullable int? If not, its grayed out because int's can never be null.

Comment: And member variables (which it is) are initialized to their default value, which is 0 in this case, when the class is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

`QtyOrdered` cannot be `null` since `null` is not a valid value for an `int`, same for any `struct`.

Comment: You just copied SledgeHammer's answer.

Comment: @nhouser9: I wrote an answer to the edited version that didn't include an out of date question and gave a term that could be used to explore if the questioner wanted to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Value types (int, long, enum, etc. ) cannot be null. Assignment will never be reached and is therefore grayed out.